# dragging image around canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I am working on a react application at the minute that has some functionality that allows the user to drag and image around the canvas and reposition it, I have move functionality working but it's not particularly nice, it just seems to redraw a new image over the top of the old giving an image within an image within an image feedback. Secondly the it seems to drag to the top left corner of the of image not the click point I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is an example, https://j3mzp8yxwy.codesandbox.io/, and my react code below,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import styled from "styled-components";

import { toggleCommentModal, setCommentPos } from '../../actions/index';
import CommentHandle from "../../CommentHandle";

class ConnectedCanvasStage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
        this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this);
        this.handleMouseUp = this.handleMouseUp.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            dragging : false,
            dragoffx : 0,
            dragoffy : 0
        }

    }

    render() {

        const CanvasStage = styled.div`
            width: 100%;
            height: ${document.body.clientHeight}px;
            position:relative;
        `;

        return(
            <CanvasStage>

                <canvas id="canvas"
                          ref="canvas"
                          width={document.body.clientWidth - (document.body.clientWidth * 0.10)}
                          height={document.body.clientHeight}
                          onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
                          onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}
                          onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
                />
            </CanvasStage>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.updateCanvas();
    }

    updateCanvas(x=0, y=0) {
        this.ctx = this.refs.canvas.getContext("2d");
        let base_image = new Image();
        base_image.src = this.props.image;
        base_image.onload = () => {
            this.ctx.drawImage(base_image, x, y, (document.body.clientWidth - (document.body.clientWidth * 0.10)) * 2, document.body.clientHeight * 2);
        }
    }

    handleMouseDown(event) {
        switch(this.props.activeTool) {
            case "move":
                let mx = event.clientX;
                let my = event.clientY;
                let pos = this.getRelativeClickPosition(document.getElementById('canvas'), event);
                this.setState({
                    dragging: !this.state.dragging,
                    dragoffx : parseInt(mx - pos.x),
                    dragoffy : parseInt(my - pos.y)
                });
            break;

            case "comment":
                let comment_position = this.getRelativeClickPosition(document.getElementById('canvas'), event);
                this.addComment(comment_position.x, comment_position.y);
            break;
        }
    }

    handleMouseMove(event) {
        if(this.props.activeTool == 'move' && this.state.dragging) {

                var dx = event.clientX - this.state.dragoffx;
                var dy = event.clientY - this.state.dragoffy;

                this.updateCanvas(dx, dy);

        }
    }

    handleMouseUp() {
        this.setState({
            dragging :false
        });
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    addComment(x, y) {
        x = x - 24;
        y = y - 20;
        this.props.toggleCommentModal(true);
        this.props.setCommentPos({x, y});
    }

    getRelativeClickPosition(canvas, event) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: event.clientX - rect.left,
            y: event.clientY - rect.top
        };

    }

}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        toggleCommentModal : visible => dispatch(toggleCommentModal(visible)),
        setCommentPos : position => dispatch(setCommentPos(position))
    };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        activeTool : state.activeTool,
        comments : state.comments
    }
};

const CanvasStage = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedCanvasStage);
export default CanvasStage;
```

How would I go about smoothing this drag out so it doesn't just draw a  new image on top and it also drags from the click point and not the top left of the image?

Comment: The example you've linked doesn't appear to work for me. In any case, the effect you are noticing "it just seems to redraw a new image" is completely normal. If you wish to do a "drag effect" you need to clear what was previously drawn on the canvas, otherwise it'll just stay there when you redraw a new image on the canvas. clearRect method is the one you need.

Comment: click on the image, don't release and drag. That should work I have just tested it myself.